# forum posts have inappropriate, invisible line breaks

Tags: php, css

I cannot for the life of me figure out why, when people post on my php forum (called Just A Forum, from codecanyon [unsupported]), the posts tend to look like this:

[image: forum post sample screenshot]

Inspecting with chrome dev tools, the text looks fine and I don't see any evidence of line-breaks. I've played around with the textarea width, making it match the text container width, but that doesn't seem to help. Neither did making sure the padding also matches, the font, etc.

Rather than post a bunch of CSS that could turn out to be irrelevant, I guess I'll wait for some instruction. I really just would like a clue as to where I should look, things I could try. I don't even know where to begin, with this.

Comment: You want us to just lob guesses or are you going to post the code that generates that image?

Comment: It's Friday! Let's lob guesses @j08691! Besides, I hate it when line breaks are *inappropriate*, it so ruins an afternoon.

Comment: Yeah I'm a huge loser bc I don't know YOUR lingo and spend my days coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, wrap="hard" was the culprit.